# Make only 1 http call for chai-http unit-testing in Node?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying out the [chai-http](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http) plugin for Mocha/Chai.  Which wraps around Superagent.  Everything seems to work well, except I'm wondering...

Shouldn't I be able to make the http call once and write separate tests for each?  The tests seem to expect you to write your assertion inside the response function like so:

```
describe "github test", ->

   it "should connect with a 200 status", ->
     chai.request(githubReqObj.base)
      .get(githubReqObj.url)
      .req (req) ->
         req.set
           'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.beta+json'
         return
      .res (res) ->
         expect(res).to.have.status 200
```

But I want to run several assertions, and have each of them under their own "it" block.

Is there a way to run

```
   before ->
```

And then just call my assertions on the value of response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, like this:

```
describe("github test", function () {
    var res;

    before(function (done) {
        chai.request(...)
            .get(..)
            .req(...)
            .res(function (response) {
                res = response; // Record the response for the tests.
                done(); // Tell mocha that the ``before`` callback is done.
            });
    });

    it("should connect with a 200 status", function () {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
    });

    it("should whaterver", function () {
        expect(res).whatever;
    });
});
```

I notice you did not use the `done` callback in your example. It's really important to use it for asynchronous tests. In the code I show above, the `before` callback is asynchronous but the tests themselves are synchronous.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response @Louis, and done() makes perfect sense.

Comment: But, I've set up my function like your example, and I get a 404.  When I move it back, I get the expected 200.  Am I missing something?  I can show you my code, but it is pretty much exactly what you have above...

Comment: This is the error:  AssertionError: expected { Object (req, res, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 404

Comment: I'm puzzled. Just moving the code around like I suggested should not change the status of the response. Is it possible to see the new code? (A gist on github would be perfect for this, but I'll look at it by whatever means you want to use.)

Comment: Thanks again Louis, I really appreciate it.  I made a gist here:  https://gist.github.com/seethroughtrees/7864387

Comment: Hey Louis, I think the problem is more on my side.  The simplified version is passing, but i don't think its actually running the test.  Your answer is perfect, and will get me exactly where I want to go.  Thanks again.

Comment: The answer was that I needed a blank string inside the .get() method!  .get('') fixed the issue!!

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem. I was off the computer for about one hour or so, hence the silence on my part.

Comment: Definitely wouldn't have gotten there without you.  Thanks Louis!